# Relative redirect to directories' main page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect every wrong request in my websites directory `www.mysite.com/dir/` to be redirected to the main page.

For example, `www.mysite.com/dir/doesnotexist` will be redirected to `www.mysite.com/dir/`.

I found several solutions to this problem, but none of these work relative to the directory itself (most use a .htaccess file in an upper directory, which stores the rewrite rules). I don't want to change the .htaccess file content when I rename the directory, so I want a .htaccess file in the directory with the rewrite rules that don't rely on the directory name.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want rules that you can place in any directory that will send potential 404 not found request to the index of the directory, you can just use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/ [L,R]
```

So if you place those rules inthe directory: `/foo/bar/`, then request a file that doesn't exist: `/foo/bar/some/file-blah`, you'll simply get redirected to `/foo/bar/`